# Converting a UNIX epoch to a Date Object

Tags: r, unix, gps, epoch

I am trying to convert a supposedly UNIX epoch (obtained from GPS) to date object in R. I tried to use the following code, but I got an unrealistic answer as a result (shown below). Could anybody tell me what type of UNIX this is and how to convert it ?

```
x <- 2.01604*10^13 # Unix epoch I need to convert

as.POSIXct(as.numeric(as.character(x)), origin="1970-01-01", tz="Asia/Shanghai")

> > "640827-08-24 07:06:40 CST" # result
```

Comment: Are you sure your origin is "1970-01-01" or that this isn't milliseconds instead of seconds? Do you know what range the dates should be in too?

Comment: Thanks for response. 
When I try to involve milliseconds (= dividing the timestamp by 1000), I get 
[1] "2608-11-10 07:06:40 CST" as a result. 
No, I am not sure about the origin. The range should be April-June, 2016.

Comment: One option maybe - http://www.oc.nps.edu/oc2902w/gps/timsys.html ?

Comment: I will check it out now. But the epoch 2.01604*10^13 seems too large for the origin 1970-01-01. This is a road(traffic) data obtained from GPS.

Comment: On second thoughts this looks like just a date as text. `201604*10^13` is `20160400000000` which looks like 2016, then 04 for the month which would be the start of April 2016. Not sure about the rest but that seems to fit with your date range.

Comment: Thanks for this useful comment !!! I will try to reexamine the issue on the actual dataset.

Comment: Your suggestion  is quite on-point. But the problem is that, according to the description, the timestamp also includes time (hh, mm, ss).

Comment: `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS` would be the format I imagine. But that is a big guess on my part. So maybe `as.POSIXct(x, format="%Y%m%d%H%M%S")`

Comment: Thanks. Your guess was actually correct. I used strptime(x, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S") to convert the number into a Date object.